# Unable to include file from library Clion

Tags: c++, json, cmake, clion

I've been trying to include the JSON for modern c++ ([GitHub page](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/README.md)) library for a school project. The integration part of the README requires the user to add a simple line of code to the .cpp file that will be using the library. However, the lines provide an error since within the included file, the designer included other files using the #include<>. I am using Clion which uses Cmake. I am currently unable to run the program without receiving the following error message:

```
fatal error: nlohmann/json.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
```

My code goes as follows:

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

// for convenience
using json = nlohmann::json;
```

My Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(assingment_5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories( CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/nlohmann)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp sample Item.cpp Item.h)
add_executable(assingment_5 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The `nlohmann` folder is within the root directory of the project

---

UPDATE:

Thanks all for the answers.

The problem CMake problem has been solved by @Justin (Complete fix in the comments). I am aware that there are multiple ways of solving it but this is the one that I chose.

The new CMakeLists.txt now looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(assingment_5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)

#[[include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})   <------ works as well]]

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp sample Item.cpp Item.h)
add_executable(assingment_5 ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(assingment_5 PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: If the **json** root directory is in the same directory as your CMakeLists.txt, you should be able to write `add_subdirectory(nlohmann)`, then after your `add_executable`, write `target_link_libraries(assignment_5 PRIVATE nlohmann_json)`, even though that's not the most idiomatic way to do it

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It didn't work... It get some Cmake related errors: ` CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /cygdrive/c/Users/Etienne/Documents/GitHub/Collaboration/assingment 5/nlohmann

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "assignment_5" which is not built
  by this project`

Comment: Oh what is the `nlohmann` directory?

Comment: My CMakeLists.txt is located at the root of the project. The nlohmann library is one level deeper. Which can be expressed as: src/nlohmann/json.hpp. where src is the folder containing the CMakeLists

Comment: Is it just **json.hpp** in **src/nlohmann/**? Where did you get this file (can you link the page and/or give a description of the steps you used to download it)?

Comment: Sure, I found it on github. The link is in the original content. Within "integration" section of the readme there's a release link. Download the first one and I added the nlohman folder to my src folder.

Comment: Okay. Scratch what I said before. I understand now that what you want is `target_include_directories(assingment_5 PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` (you could use `include_directories` like you were in the Question, but it's more idiomatic CMake to use `target_include_directories`). The problem in your original code was twofold: 1. You wrote `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, when you should write `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. 2. You are including the `nlohmann` in the include path; you don't want to do that

Comment: The `include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})` did the trick! However using the `target_include_directories(assingment_5 PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` gave an error: `Cannot specify include directories for target "assingment_5" which is not
  built by this project.` At this point, you did solve my problem and I am extremely grateful for it! Thanks a lot and have a good day.

Comment: Make sure the `target_include_directories` line is *after* the `add_executable` line and it should work

Answer (score 2):

For *simplicity*, I started using that header like this:

I have the header within my current directory which makes for a simple CMakeLists.txt. After all, I just wanted to explore the *library*.

[image]

[image]

Now you can use the described `using` declaration like so and be off and running.

[image]